# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape' on jupyter notebook

Tags: numpy, opencv, jupyter-notebook

So I have this problem where I am trying to load an image data into jupyter notebook. I have no problem loading imgA as when I check the image using print(imgA) the matrices is displayed, while imgB keeps on giving me a notype attribute error even though both the image is saved in the same folder.

Here are my codes:

```
imgA = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\Dzaky Ligarwaly-R\\Documents\\pattern recognition\\Biomedical_Image.jpg")
imgB = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\Dzaky Ligarwaly-R\\Documents\\pattern recognition\\pano.jpg")
```

Here are my codes with the resize:

```
scale_percent = 60 # percentage of original size
# imgA
width = int(imgA.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(imgA.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dimA = (width, height)
# imgB
width = int(imgB.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(imgB.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dimB = (width, height)
```

Comment: either the path is not correct or images are corrupter. try `print(imgA)` and `print(imgB)`. Should give `None`.

Comment: `imread` returns None when it can't read the file

Comment: Ok so I checked the path and it was correct so I decided to delete and download the file again and it worked. It worked. I'll be sure to be more careful with the image condition to avoid this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have the wrong path. Maybe try to look out for your file path or name as this is a recurring mistake when trying to load an image.